# Heroku issue, ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Loading without problem on localhost:3000, but once deployed to Heroku I am receiving the following error. Ran

```
heroku logs --tail

2013-08-29T04:38:23.403690+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-08-29T04:38:26.898295+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-29 04:38:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-08-29T04:38:26.898295+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-29 04:38:26] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
2013-08-29T04:38:26.898634+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-29 04:38:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=11226
2013-08-29T04:38:27.010520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-29T04:38:28.496863+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.148.15.124 at 2013-08-29 04:38:28 +0000
2013-08-29T04:38:28.642277+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
2013-08-29T04:38:29.529140+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=afternoon-gorge-1648.herokuapp.com fwd="50.148.15.124" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=1081ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-08-29T04:38:29.541662+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered events/_event.html.erb (320.3ms)
2013-08-29T04:38:29.541795+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered events/index.html.erb within layouts/application (743.9ms)
2013-08-29T04:38:29.542093+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 900ms
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   <td><%= event.title %></td>
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <td><%= event.location %></td>
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <td><%= event.description %></td>
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <td><strong><%= link_to event.user.name, event.user %></strong></td>
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <% if current_user == event.user %>
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544607+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/events/_event.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_events__event_html_erb___4373324357052961172_69914882818260'
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544790+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/events/index.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_events_index_html_erb___3028579038251132182_69914889655380'
2013-08-29T04:38:29.544790+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

I have already confirmed that my databases locally and on Heroku match. 
The app only fails when logged in. The landing page loads fine when logged out. 
This happened when I added new 7 new User fields my database, all strings. 
Ran

```
rake db:migrate
```

locally.

Ran

```
heroku run rake db:migrate.
```

Here is the Heroku link: http://afternoon-gorge-1648.herokuapp.com/

Very confused as to where the problem lies.

UPDATE: Here is the events index page:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>Sign up for any of the following events!</h1>
  </div>
  <h1>Listing events</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Posted by</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <%= render @events %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <%= link_to 'Add New Event', new_event_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'pages/home' %>
<% end %>
```

Calls the _event.html.erb partial:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= image_tag event.image(:medium) %></td>
  <td><%= event.title %></td>
  <td><%= event.location %></td>
  <td><%= event.description %></td>
  <td><strong><%= link_to event.user.name, event.user %></strong></td>
  <td><small><%= link_to 'Show', event %></small></td>
  <% if current_user == event.user %>
    <td><small><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></small></td>
    <td><small><%= link_to 'Delete', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></small></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Comment: You've received two thorough answers below. It'd be helpful if you indicated whether either has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to invoke the render partial shorthand. However, the shorthand can only be used for *singular* objects, but you're trying to pass _a collectio_n of objects. Instead, you need to loop through `@events` and pass each resulting `event` as a local to your partial:

```
# app/views/events/index.html.erb
<% @events.each do |event| %>    
    <%= render :partial => 'events', :locals => {:event => event} %>
<% end %>
```

To understand more regarding why the syntax you've invoked doesn't work, see section *3.4.4 Passing Local Variables* in the [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). Basically, the `_event.html.erb` partial is expecting a singular object (which it *would* access via the `event` local variable), but instead, you're passing it a collection of multiple `Event` objects. So, while the local variable `events` is available to the partial, `event` isn't.

Since you're still trying to access attributes/relations on the `event` variable (which doesn't exist) you're receiving the `NilClass` error. Thus, looping through each event and explicitly passing that event to the partial should resolve your error.

Comment: The events render locally on my computer. Is there a reason why they render locally but do not render when pushing through Heroku? Also, this partial shorthand worked before I committed the changes my Users database. Did my updates to the Users database cause this app to break only on Heroku?

Comment: How many events are saved on you local machine? If there's just one, then it'd work.

Comment: Did you get any resolution to this?

Comment: Thank you so much. This did work. @zeantsoi 's explanation of the problem was also very helpful. So sorry for the delay in answering.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `event` is coming through as one object of many from a block (something like `@events.each do |event|...`).  Do you have bad seed data where it's producing an event row with no data?  You could run `heroku run rails c` and then `events = Event.all` and see if there is strange looking data (nulls) in there.

EDIT:
It would also be helpful to see more of the error.  Is `name` being called on an `event` object or something else?

Comment: Updated the code above. Ran rails console to check users = User.all and all users have nil fields. The 7 fields I did add to the User database are all nil for my Heroku users. I assume the problem somewhere with users because that was my last db migrations. These migrations are working locally, but are breaking my Heroku app.

Comment: Similar to what zeantsoi is saying, perhaps you have only one event locally so it's coming through okay whereas on production you have many events?